# Is there a function-hiding functional encryption for quadratic polynomials?

Tags: functional-encryption

Recently, I have found research papers about the functional encryptions for inner products and quadratic polynomials.
For inner products, there are a few papers which focus to construct efficient function hiding functional encryption for inner products. However, I could not find any results about the function hiding functional encryption for quadratic polynomials.

Is there a paper for the function hiding functional encryption for quadratic polynomials?

If not, what is the main obstacle to build the function hiding functional encryption for quadratic polynomials?
Moreover, what is the implication of the existence of this scheme?

Comment: You might like to look at "[Evaluating 2-DNF formulas on cipher texts](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-30576-7_18)" by Boneh, Goh and Nissim, which specialises to the quadratic case. More recent papers on fully-homomorphic encryption (FHE) focus on the evaluation of general polynomial expressions.

Comment: @DanielS Thanks. However, as I know, it is impossible to construct a public key function hiding functional encryption. Thus I think the paper might not be a different kind of answer.